# Como configurar o HttpClient do Java para aceitar JavaScript e Cookies?

Tags: javascript, java, cookies

Eu preciso com que o meu retorno HttpClient consiga rodar um JavaScript e carregar cookies dentro dele, alguém sabe como configura ele pra que isso possa ser possível?

Grato

Comment: HttpClient serve para fazer uma requisição Http e não emular (*o comportamento que teria em*) um navegador. [**HtmlUnit**](http://sourceforge.net/projects/htmlunit/files/htmlunit/) e [**Selenium**](http://docs.seleniumhq.org/) possuem suporte a Javascript.

Comment: Talvez o Nashorn te interesse: http://www.infoq.com/br/articles/nashorn

Comment: Como funciona esse HtmlUnit, e esse Selenium, re22?